# Numpy: convert index in one dimension into many dimensions

Tags: numpy, scipy

Many array methods return a single index despite the fact that the array is multidimensional. For example:

```
a = rand(2,3)
z = a.argmax()
```

For two dimensions, it is easy to find the matrix indices of the maximum element:

```
a[z/3, z%3]
```

But for more dimensions, it can become annoying. Does Numpy/Scipy have a simple way of returning the indices in multiple dimensions given an index in one (collapsed) dimension? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe annoying, but quite doable.

Comment: Indeed it is! See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

```
a = X.argmax()
(i,j) = unravel_index(a, X.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats interesting, it actually helps me solve some problems I couldn't solve with my own solution without some hacks, where the sape of b is a extension of the shape of a

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an built-in function that does what you want, but where this
has come up for me, I realized that what I really wanted to do was this:

given 2 arrays a,b with the same shape, find the element of b which is in
the same position (same [i,j,k...] position) as the maximum element of a

For this, the quick numpy-ish solution is:

```
j = a.flatten().argmax()
corresponding_b_element = b.flatten()[j]
```

Vince Marchetti